# Grouping by unique child associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, grouping

I want to group parent objects based on their child associations. I’m struggling to describe this so I’ll jump into the example.

Lets say that we want to group `Films` by the unique group of `Actors` featured in them. An Actor can be in multiple groups, but the group of actors is unique to the group.

Example:

```
Film A
    Actor with id 34
    Actor with id 45

Film B
    Actor with id 45

Film C
    Actor with id 34
    Actor with id 45

Film D
    Actor with id 34
    Actor with id 45
    Actor with id 21

Film E
    Actor with id 34
    Actor with id 45
    Actor with id 21

Film F
    Actor with id 34
```

In the example I would expect `Film A` and `Film C` to be grouped together, `Film D` and `Film E` to be grouped together, while `Film B` and `Film F` would be grouped separately in their own groups.

If I was doing this with attributes I would use `Film.where(actor_id: id).first_or_initialize`, but this particular problem requires it to work with a **dynamic** number of **child associations**, so I'm unsure how to do it.

Comment: what output do you expect?

Comment: It depends on the solution, nothing is fixed yet. I'm planning on creating a new record in a new class called `FilmGroup`, which will have child `Film` and `Actor` associations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final solution was actually quite simple, but not so elegant. I stored a string format of the uniquely sorted array of the child associations (`Actors`) and used it to `find_or_initialize` the group.

I'm using `nested attributes` to save the actors in the `attributes` array, I find its a little faster because it uses `INSERT INTO`.

```
film = Film.find(some_id)     
actor_ids = film.actors.map {|a| a.id}.sort.uniq
attributes = []
for id in actor_ids
  attributes << {actor_id: id}
end
film_group = FilmGroup.where(actor_array: actor_ids.to_s).first_or_initialize
film_group.update(actor_count: actor_ids.count, actors_attributes: attributes, films_attributes: [{film_id: film.id}])
```

I'm sure there is a better way.. but this works.